# Vue - Laravel - SPA 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I don't know why I'm getting this error.

> [image]

After checking the network tab, it only displays "message:"Server Error"

> [image]

This only occurs randomly when changing routes and refreshing the page. Sometimes it won't appear, sometimes it would appear. It also happens to my other `api` with `get` function.

**routes.js**

```
  { 
    path: '/', 
    redirect: '/dashboard',
    component: () => import('@/views/BaseView'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
      { 
        path: '/dashboard', 
        name: 'dashboard', 
        component: () => import('@/views/Dashboard'),
      },
      { 
        path: 'objective/employee/:id', 
        name: 'employee-objective', 
        component: () => import('@/views/employee-objective/index'),
      },
    ]
  },
```

**api**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
  Route::get('user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
  });
  Route::get('employee-objectives', 'EmployeeObjectiveController@objectives');
});
```

**laravel controller**

```
  public function objectives(Request $request) {
    $get = EmployeeObjective::with('corporateObjective:id,corporate_objective,corporate_objective_description', 
    'employeeObjectiveKpa:id,employee_objective_id,department_objective_id,kpa_info,kpi_info,kpi_progress,kpa_weight,kpa_score_1,kpa_equal,created_at')
    ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
    ->first();
    return response()->json($get);
  }
```

**component.vue**

```
 created() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.state.loading = false;
      },1000);
      this.getEmployeeObjectiveKPA()
    },

 methods: {
      getEmployeeObjectiveKPA() {
        axios.get('/api/employee-objectives', { 
          params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id } 
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.employee_objective_kpa !== undefined) {
            this.employee_objective_kpa = response.data.employee_objective_kpa
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

        <title>Appraisal</title>

        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script>window.Laravel = { csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }</script>

  </head>
```

**storage/logs/laravel** (I trimmed it down, it's #35 lines of error)

```
[2020-03-02 19:59:44] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at C:\\laragon\\www\\appraisal\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\appraisal\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(422): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(NULL)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\appraisal\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php(48): tap(NULL, Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Have you tried checking your server side logs to see if any exceptions are being thrown? I would enable debug mode in your `.env` file so that you can see the error.

Comment: My `.env` is already set to `APP_DEBUG=true` but I'm not really sure on how to use it.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as how your Laravel and Vue routes are setup?

Comment: Hello @tamrat please see my edited post.

Comment: issue seems to be at the laravel side, may be recheck the query execution ?
please check https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#logging

Comment: I'll try to recheck my query execution.

Comment: I think I have found the culprit. I'm getting my `params` from the `vuex store` so it might have something to do with fetching the data from it.

Comment: Posted my storage/logs/laravel

Answer (score 0):

How did you get this query and what are you trying to do?
The `with()` method is to load model relationships eagerly. Also, the `', '` in the middle is quite invalid. As it should be an array of relationships OR one single string for a relationship.

```
$get = EmployeeObjective::with('corporateObjective:id,corporate_objective,corporate_objective_description', 
'employeeObjectiveKpa:id,employee_objective_id,department_objective_id,kpa_info,kpi_info,kpi_progress,kpa_weight,kpa_score_1,kpa_equal,created_at')
```

Are these just properties of the EmployeeObjective? Use `select()` for that. Also, you have colons in there, why?

Also, if i am correct, you can return the result of the query immediately. No need to call the response method as it will automatically JSONify your result when returned.

Comment: The use of `with('relationship:column', relationship:column)`, It's the properties/columns of the relationship model. I'm only trying to load the columns I needed for fetching the data, thus lowering it's size.  Roughly around 400kb was reduced. (though I'm not sure if it really affects users loading in general).

Oh I'll remove the json now, thanks for that.

Comment: Ah i see, misread the docs a bit there. Anyway, maybe wrap it in an array then. Like this: `with(['corporateObjective:id,corporate_objective,corporate_objective_description', 
'employeeObjectiveKpa:id,employee_objective_id,department_objective_id,kpa_info,kpi_info,kpi_progress,kpa_weight,kpa_score_1,kpa_equal,created_at'])`

If it still does not work then please add your EmployeeObjective model code :)

Comment: Oh and did you include the id's and foreign keys of the relations? According to docs: `When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.`

Comment: Yes I have managed to include the `id` and `foreign key` of the relationship model. After adding the `[ ]` inside `with()` somehow the error is rarely appearing now, though it might be coincidental (like I said this error just pops out of nowhere from time to time). Thank you for this one. I will still try and refresh my component more times.

Comment: When requesting the same Employee id? You have debug mode turned on. Maybe check your logs. `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: Ohhhhh thats a really easy fix. You do not have an encryption key set which is used for cookie encryption. Please run `php artisan key:generate` in your root directory. This will set the `APP_KEY` value in your `.env` file and should fix the problem!

Comment: `APP_KEY` was set but yeah this is also one of the culprits according to what I have read. Thank you for this! But I posted the answer, it was about the cache `php artisan config:cache`. Man this was really a headache. Thank you very much for keeping in touch with me, I really appreciate it. Have a great day ahead man!

Comment: No problem at all. Don't forget to mark your question as answered! Have a great day yourself. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves everything. `php artisan config:cache`

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25964

Can anyone explain this solution?